# MySQL SELECT query with sequenced filter conditions

Tags: mysql, select, sequence, where-clause

Hope the title is not that confusing - honestly said I had no idea how to better explain my problem in a single line :-) (and Google it properly BTW)

A table 'group' is structured as a nested set to create tree menues. Articles in a table 'article' reference to ID of such group element to - well - group them:

```
Table 'article'                     Table 'group'
id   |   article      |   groupid           id   |  title    |   left    |   right
1    |   Bowl         |   2                 1    |  material |   1       |   6
2    |   Bowl         |   5                 2    |  wood     |   2       |   3
3    |   Cube         |   3                 3    |  steel    |   4       |   5
4    |   Cube         |   6                 4    |  shape    |   6       |   13
5    |   Bowl         |  10                 5    |  circle   |   7       |   8
6    |   Pyramid      |   2                 6    |  square   |   9       |   10
7    |   Pyramid      |   3                 7    |  rectangle|   11      |   12
8    |   Pyramid      |  11                 8    |  color    |   14      |   21
9    |   Bowl         |  11                 9    |  red      |   15      |   16
10   |   Cube         |   9                10    |  green    |   17      |   18
11   |   Pyramid      |   9                11    |  blue     |   19      |   20
```

To select any combination of group elements, I simply have a query mentioning a range from group.left to group.right, giving me a set of group.id that I can compare with article.groupid.
Following statement responds all articles consisting of wood:

```
SELECT
   a.article
FROM
   article AS a
LEFT JOIN 
   group AS g
ON (
      (
         2 >= g.left
      AND
         3 <= g.right
      AND
         g.id = a.groupid
      )
   )
GROUP BY
   a.article
```

Now my question: how should I create a query, that responds with e.g. all articles that consist of wood AND have ANY color?
I expected that repeating concatenated subqueries in the WHERE clause would make the deal:

```
SELECT
    a.article
FROM
    article AS a
WHERE
    a.groupid IN
        (
            SELECT
                CONCAT(g.id) AS gr
            FROM
                group AS g
            WHERE
                (
                    2 >= g.left 
                AND
                    3 <= g.right
                )
        )
AND
    a.groupid IN
        (
            SELECT
                CONCAT(g.id) AS gr
            FROM
                group AS g
            WHERE
                (
                    14 >= g.left 
                AND
                    21 <= g.right
                )
        )
```

This query responds no result. BTW I dont like subqueries but many efforts with JOINS and Sub-JOINS did not work as well.
My mind is spinning - any tips from you guys?

Thanks

Comment: Why are you specifying the `right` and `left` values?  Can you not just join on the `group.id` property?  Is there any way you can change your schema, because it seems like its fighting you instead of helping you?

Comment: Nope. No article is referenced to 'material', 'shape' or 'color' (ID 1, 4 and 8) - those are tree menu headers, but I need to be able to capture articles related to all elements of such header.

Comment: How are you supposed to differentiate between what a header is and what is a type of header?  Seems like there are going to be some problems down the line unless you hard code the id of the headers in.

Comment: The left/right coordinates define the level and the affiliation of each record - see nested set model

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**edited: now working. [Test it here (but in MSSQL)](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/qt/123811/)**

First approach based on your query, problem comes from non well normalized design. To do the query you will to check **if exists a row on articles with same name** that references a kind of property:

```
SELECT
    distinct a.article
FROM
    article AS a
WHERE
    exists 
      (      
           SELECT
                1
            FROM
                group AS g
            INNER JOIN
                article as a2
                on g.id = a2.groupid
            WHERE 
                a2.article = a.article and
                (2 <= g.left AND 3 >= g.right)
       ) and
      exists (
           SELECT
                1
            FROM
                group AS g
            INNER JOIN
                article as a2
                on g.id = a2.groupid
            WHERE 
                a2.article = a.article and
                (14 <= g.left AND 21 >= g.right)
        )
```

**Edited**

OP uses nested sets. But perhaps article's table is still not well normalized. I suggest to take in consideration this design:

```
article( id, name )
groupNestedSet( id, title, left, right )
article_group( idArticle, idGroup)
```

sample normalized data:

```
article( id, name )
1, Bowl   (only one time)
3, Cube   (also only one time)

groupNestedSet( id, title, left, right )
-- your data --

article_group( idArticle, idGroup)
1, 2
1, 5
3, 3
3, 5
...
```

Comment: What is "not normalized" in the design?

Comment: You removed the hierarchy definition from the group table. You also don't know if the column `article` isn't in fact the article's title and therefor it wouldn't make sense to create a separate entity for it.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, with a well normalized design the query will be really simple!

Comment: I still think the article_property might be overdone. But only the OP can answer this - from the sample data you might be right, but you might be wrong as well. Btw: using an adjencency model for a hierarchy in MySQL is not a very good idea, because MySQL still doesn't support hierarchical queries (aka recursive CTEs)

Comment: @danihp thanks so far but did not end up in a success. A word about normalization: the actual tables are structured exactly the way you propose - I simply replaced idArticle by article name and left the 3rd table out for better clarity in this post

Comment: @droehn, now working. [you can test it](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/qt/123811/)

Comment: @danihp indeed, working :-) And it widened my understanding of query mechanics in MySQL. Great job, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The problem isn't the SQL; you're asking for records with a groupid between 2 & 3 in the first section, AND between 14 and 21 in the second.  No record can match that criteria.

Maybe what you really want is to find all articles that are wood, all those that are color, and then find all that are in both.

Comment: Yep - now I can see. In PHP I would first query against 2&3 and use this result to query it against 14&21. Is it possible to combine this into one single query?

Comment: Sure; just do a JOIN between the queries for each of the materials; the result should be a list of the articles in both.